# What's a good algorithm for nearest neighbour problem in two dimensions?

Tags: algorithm, geolocation, nearest-neighbor

I would like to build an app that's going to give you the closest restaurant depending on your location. We'll have a database with all the POI corresponding to the restaurant and we'll get your location with the GPS of your phone...

What algorithm would be appropriate ? Where can I find good doc about it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an informative presentation: http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/Workshops/MiningTutorial/pindyk-slides.ppt

I would either use a [Quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) or a [Kd-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree).

See some benchmarks here: http://www.flegg.net/brett/pubs/spatial/index.html. It really all depends on your data size and range.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is how do you store and search the data. If you are using a SQL database that doesn't support spatial indexes (let's say SQLite on Android), consider converting the spatial data to a linear [Z-order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_%28curve%29) curve. The algorithm is simple, I know about (well, wrote) [this](http://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/tools/MultiDimension.java) implementation.

Comment: Doing nearest neighbor queries on a large database doesn't seem like a good thing to do directly on android anyway. The database server is there to do heavy lifting like this in the first place.

Comment: @Tim I agree Z-order isn't all that great for a large database. By the way, since my answer in 2010, I have implemented an [R-Tree](http://h2database.com/html/mvstore.html#r_tree) which should allow efficient nearest-neighbour queries (once that's implemented) and should work on Android as well. But it doesn't use SQLite.